# PhpExcel - Print View - Row height cuts off cell

Tags: php, phpexcel

My Problem is that while everything is displayed correctly in the sheet, when I want to print the specified area cells with more than one row of text get cut through in the last line of the cell:

[How it looks in the print view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggTb9.png)

I cannot set the width of the columns to auto size, because a fixed column width is wished for every column.

I have set the page to fit on one page in width and infinite pages in height

each column has text wrap set.

Other stzles are:
- font - Verdana, 10
- border - all, thin
- alignment - vertical, top

While looping through all rows and setting the values, I have tried to set the hight of the row to -1, but this doesn't do anything and if I output the height of the row, it is -1 either way.

One more thing: To the first and second row, different styles apply.

Help is very much appreciated. I really don't know how I could make this look decent.

Comment: [PHPExcel has been depecrated](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). You should switch to [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Comment: I know, but this is sadly not up to me.